# roslaunch error-Amazon EC2- X Error of failed request: BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)

Tags: ros-kinetic, ubuntu-16.04, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I have an Oracle VirtualBox VM with Ubuntu 16.04 and ROS Kinetic installed, in which I run Gazebo using the following command for a simulation project:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch world_file:=<world file name>
```

I created an image (in .ova format) of this VM using the export appliance option in VirtualBox and imported it as an AMI in Amazon EC2. I launched a new EC2 instance (**t3a.2xlarge**) using this AMI and setup Ubuntu desktop for this instance following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ljvgwmJCUjw) tutorial.

After logging in to the EC2 instance using TightVNC, I used the single machine configuration in [this](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/NetworkSetup) tutorial to set environment variables to initialize roscore.

**After this when I execute the above Gazebo command I get the following error:**

```
... logging to /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/deb4dc68-daab-11ea-8688-0ae27ab79f70/roslaunch-ip-----------------------------.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

xacro: Traditional processing is deprecated. Switch to --inorder processing!
To check for compatibility of your document, use option --check-order.
For more infos, see http://wiki.ros.org/xacro#Processing_Order
xacro.py is deprecated; please use xacro instead
started roslaunch server http://ip-172-31-33-240:42337/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /bumper2pointcloud/pointcloud_radius: 0.24
 * /cmd_vel_mux/yaml_cfg_file: /opt/ros/kinetic/...
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/output_frame_id: /camera_depth_frame
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/range_min: 0.45
 * /depthimage_to_laserscan/scan_height: 10
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /robot_state_publisher/publish_frequency: 30.0
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    bumper2pointcloud (nodelet/nodelet)
    cmd_vel_mux (nodelet/nodelet)
    depthimage_to_laserscan (nodelet/nodelet)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    laserscan_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    mobile_base_nodelet_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    spawn_turtlebot_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [3318]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to deb4dc68-daab-11ea-8688-0ae27ab79f70
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [3331]
started core service [/rosout]
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [3334]
process[spawn_turtlebot_model-3]: started with pid [3339]
process[mobile_base_nodelet_manager-4]: started with pid [3340]
process[cmd_vel_mux-5]: started with pid [3341]
process[bumper2pointcloud-6]: started with pid [3342]
process[robot_state_publisher-7]: started with pid [3343]
process[laserscan_nodelet_manager-8]: started with pid [3344]
process[depthimage_to_laserscan-9]: started with pid [3345]
[ INFO] [1597024232.401174758]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1597024232.401845265]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  148 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  21
  Current serial number in output stream:  21
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::lock_error> >'
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 3334, exit code 134, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_gazebo/worlds/playground.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/deb4dc68-daab-11ea-8688-0ae27ab79f70/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/deb4dc68-daab-11ea-8688-0ae27ab79f70/gazebo-2*.log
```

**How would I fix this error and get Gazebo to work like it does in my VirtualBox VM?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/25681/roslaunch-error-amazon-ec2--x-error-of-failed-request:--badmatch-(invalid-parameter-attributes)/) by [Malar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30407/malar/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2020-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I figured out the issue. and running the below  command fixed it for me.

**export DISPLAY=:10**

---

Originally posted by [Malar](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/30407/malar/) with karma: 1 on 2020-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0